# How do I get my saves back after using a character manager in skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

I started using character manager v2 today only to find out that it didn't work and deleted all my characters instead. Is there a way to get my characters back?

Comment: If you're going to edit save files in anything, back them up first.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about this program [Skyrim Character Manager V2 by SlipperyFish](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/2119/).

From the discussion this seems to be an abandoned utility with a bunch of problems, not something that should be used.

This (copied verbatim from the discussion) should allow you to uninstall it. All credits to sydlet:

> Okay. For everyone who can't get rid of this mod and want your saves back to normal:
>
> 1. Go to Documents > My Games > Skyrim.
> 2. Should see a file called 'Skyrim.ini" (without quotes)
> 3. Open the file (enable admin rights if it won't let you edit the file) and look for a line called "SLocalSavePath=Saves\". If you have
>      this mod installed, it'll say, for example,
>      "SLocalSavePath=Saves\Bob\" or something to that effect.
> 4. Get rid of the character's name, changing it back to "SLocalSavePath=Saves\".
> 5. Save the file and open the folder named Saves. You should have a bunch of folders inside with each of your characters' names.
> 6. Open the folder, pick a character, move or copy/paste their saves back to the main folder.
> 7. Start the game and try to load a save. If you moved all your characters' saves back over, you should see all of them, from every
>      character instead of just the one.

Besides that the description says it creates a backup on start up, I can't seem to find where it puts that in the description, you could look around your `My Documents/My Games/Skyrim` folder, that would be a sensible place to put it.

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch man i thought i lost all my 397 hours of gameplay i can't thank you enough